# AS3 Standing Wave 3 Library Change Pitch

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

I am trying to figure out how to change the pitch of a sound in Standing Wave 3 actionscript library. I have imported a sound at 440hz(A) and am trying to change it's pitch to say a (C) note.

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at the filters? Particularly the `ResamplingFilter`. You use is by creating a new `ResamplingFilter` with 2 parameters. The first one is the source (`IAudioSource`) and the second parameter is the factor by which the frequency will be change by.

This is what it would look like:

```
var aNote:IAudioSource = new SoundSource(new ANoteSoundAsset());
var cNote:IAudioSource = new ResamplingFilter(aNote, 1.189);
player.play(cNote);
```

This would raise pitch of the the note from being A4 to approximately a C5 note.

Useful links:

- [ResamplingFilter reference](http://maxl0rd.github.com/standingwave3/asdoc/com/noteflight/standingwave3/filters/ResamplingFilter.html)
- [List of note frequencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequencies_of_notes)
- [Dev guide for the library](http://maxl0rd.github.com/standingwave3/dev-guide.html)

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply. Thanks so much.

Comment: Just coming back to this.I am interested in how you came up with the number 1.189? A4 is 440hz,C5 is 523.251. I don't see the connection?

Comment: "the factor by which the input frequency should be multiplied". By raising it from 440 to 523, you multiply 440 by 1.189 to get around 523 which is a C note.

Comment: Thanks! Not really very good at math. Say I wanted to calculate all notes from A4 to A5 (all twelve notes) is there an easy formula to do this. Thanks

Comment: Great! :) To find the factor which you need to multiply by, use this simple formula. A / B = C. In this example A = 523.251, B = 440 and C = 1.189. Then just look at a reference table to know what all the different notes frequencies are. http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone: Github moved its "Pages" from github.**com** to github.**io**.

The two resources linked above are not really gone, they just **moved** to:

http://maxl0rd.github.io/standingwave3/asdoc/com/noteflight/standingwave3/filters/ResamplingFilter.html

and

http://maxl0rd.github.io/standingwave3/dev-guide.html

respectively.